# What is the rule for multiplying in integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

What is the rule for finding the integral of the product of two functions?

Like this: ∫f(x)g(x)dx

Comment: If you know that either $f$ or $g$ are a derivate of some well known function you can apply integration by parts. However there isn't a general approach on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use integration by parts.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

$\displaystyle \int f(x)\  g'(x) \, dx = f(x) g(x) - \displaystyle \int f'(x)\  g(x) \, dx$